# Android post picture to Facebook wall

Tags: java, android, facebook, image

I am trying to post a picture to my wall on Facebook. I have managed logging in and posting text to the wall. However, when I try posting the picture, nothing happens.

I am using the [Android Facebook SDK](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk).

Here is what I have so far:

```
    Bundle params = new Bundle();
    params.putString("method", "photos.upload");

    Toast.makeText(FacebookPoster.this, "" + getIntent().getExtras().getByteArray("data").length, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    params.putByteArray("picture", getIntent().getExtras().getByteArray("data"));

    AsyncFacebookRunner mAsyncRunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner(facebook);
    mAsyncRunner.request(null, params, "POST", new SampleUploadListener(), null);
```

The Toast shows 8733, which means the byte array isn't empty

NB. Logcat output some warnings (not errors):

```
03-02 14:19:29.554: WARN/Bundle(1891): Attempt to cast generated internal exception:
03-02 14:19:29.554: WARN/Bundle(1891): java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String
03-02 14:19:29.554: WARN/Bundle(1891):     at android.os.Bundle.getByteArray(Bundle.java:1305)
03-02 14:19:29.554: WARN/Bundle(1891):     at com.facebook.android.Util.openUrl(Util.java:155)
03-02 14:19:29.554: WARN/Bundle(1891):     at com.facebook.android.Facebook.request(Facebook.java:559)
03-02 14:19:29.554: WARN/Bundle(1891):     at com.facebook.android.AsyncFacebookRunner$2.run(AsyncFacebookRunner.java:253)
03-02 14:19:29.584: WARN/Bundle(1891): Key method expected byte[] but value was a java.lang.String.  The default value <null> was returned.
```

(Shows several times underneath each other.)

**What am I doing wrong?**

---

**SOLVED.**
This is what I did to make it work:

```
facebook.authorize(this, new String[] { "publish_stream" },
        new DialogListener() {

    @Override
    public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(DialogError dialogError) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
        postToWall(values.getString(Facebook.TOKEN));                                              
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancel() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
});
```

And the helper method:

```
private void postToWall(String accessToken) {       
    Bundle params = new Bundle();

    params.putString(Facebook.TOKEN, accessToken);

    // The byte array is the data of a picture.
    params.putByteArray("picture", getIntent().getExtras().getByteArray("data"));

    try {
        facebook.request("me/photos", params, "POST");

    } catch (FileNotFoundException fileNotFoundException) {
        makeToast(fileNotFoundException.getMessage());
    } catch (MalformedURLException malformedURLException) {
        makeToast(malformedURLException.getMessage());
    } catch (IOException ioException) {
        makeToast(ioException.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: @Whirlwin... I am still getting that exception... I am also able to see this in javadoc 'Note that binary data parameters (e.g. pictures) are not yet supported by this helper' for function.facebook.request

Comment: Last time I tested it (about 40 days ago), it worked for Android 2.1. But I changed the order of some lines in the helper method `postToWall(...)`. So now, it is: `Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

     bundle.putByteArray("facebookPictureData", pictureData);
     bundle.putString(Facebook.TOKEN, accessToken);
` pluss the rest of the code that in that method which is unchanged. BTW: `pictureData` is just the byte array. Hope it works for you too. :)

Comment: @Whirlwin...+1 (for the question, answer and the comment) Thank you very much. You really helped me in a TIGHTTTTT situation. :) :) :)...

Comment: I tried your solution, however, I encounter NPE problem : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9614014/npe-when-post-image-along-with-text-caption-via-facebook-sdk

Comment: @whirlwin  facebook.authorize is not getting resolved in eclipse, kindly help.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

first thing is that you are not using graph api to upload the pictures... u r using the old rest api... try to use graph api, its simple...

Use following code:

```
Bundle param = new Bundle();
param.putString("message", "picture caption");
param.putByteArray("picture", ImageBytes);
mAsyncRunner.request("me/photos", param, "POST", new SampleUploadListener());
```

According to error message, it looks like its giving errors in getting bytes from intent's bundle...

Comment: Where can I download the Graph API?

Comment: you are already using graph api actually what i think its just the use of api.. for old rest api you need to provide the method in bundle like "photos.upload" but in graph api you provide "me/photos" in mAsyncRunner.request function....

Comment: I figured it out now, and it is much easier with the Graph API. Thanks a bunch! :)

Comment: @Farhan how can i add image here....   params.putByteArray("picture", getIntent().getExtras().getByteArray("data"));

Comment: i am getting error if i use above code The method request(String, Bundle, String, AsyncFacebookRunner.RequestListener, Object) in the type AsyncFacebookRunner is not applicable for the arguments (String, Bundle, String, Example.SampleUploadListener)

Comment: I think its because, the facebook sdk has changed a little... so get the new sdk and use the function accordingly now. for ImageBytes they are just a byte array....

Answer (score 6):

```
btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                facebook.authorize(FbdemoActivity.this, new String[]{ "user_photos,publish_checkins,publish_actions,publish_stream"},new DialogListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFacebookError(FacebookError error) {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(DialogError e) {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancel() {
                    }
                });

            }
        });

public void postImageonWall() {

           byte[] data = null;

             Bitmap bi = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("/sdcard/viewitems.png");
             ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
             bi.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
             data = baos.toByteArray();


             Bundle params = new Bundle();
             params.putString(Facebook.TOKEN, facebook.getAccessToken());
             params.putString("method", "photos.upload");
             params.putByteArray("picture", data);

             AsyncFacebookRunner mAsyncRunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner(facebook);
             mAsyncRunner.request(null, params, "POST", new SampleUploadListener(), null);

    }

public class SampleUploadListener extends BaseRequestListener {

    public void onComplete(final String response, final Object state) {
        try {
            // process the response here: (executed in background thread)
            Log.d("Facebook-Example", "Response: " + response.toString());
            JSONObject json = Util.parseJson(response);
            final String src = json.getString("src");

            // then post the processed result back to the UI thread
            // if we do not do this, an runtime exception will be generated
            // e.g. "CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original
            // thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views."

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.w("Facebook-Example", "JSON Error in response");
        } catch (FacebookError e) {
            Log.w("Facebook-Example", "Facebook Error: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e, Object state) {    
    }
}
```

try this code it will work i had used the same code and uploads the image on Facebook.

Comment: Where are your images going if you do it like this? I have an issue that my images go directly to album, and are not published to wall / timeline and do not finish in other users feed...

Comment: wht is BaseRequestListener here?

Answer (score 6):

Here is the working code sample. Pass image path and message.

```
public static void postImageonWall(String FilePath,String msg ) {

    try {

        Bitmap bi = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(FilePath);
        AsyncFacebookRunner mAsyncRunner = new   AsyncFacebookRunner(facebook);
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bi.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);  // where bm is bitmap from Sdcard
        byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
        Bundle param = new Bundle();
        param = new Bundle();
        param.putString("message", msg);
        param.putString("filename", "Dessert Dash");
        param.putByteArray("image", byteArray);
        param.putString("caption", "Dessert Dash in Android Market Now");

        mAsyncRunner.request("me/photos", param, "POST", fbrq, null);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }



}
```

Comment: buddy what is 'fbrq'?

Answer (score 4):

```
private String postwall(String uid)
    {
        String response = "";
        try
        {

            String DIRECTORY_PATH = "/sdcard/159.jpg";
            Bundle params = new Bundle();
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(DIRECTORY_PATH);
            byte[] data = null;
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
            data = baos.toByteArray();
            params.putString("app_id", uid);
            params.putString("message", "picture caption");
            params.putByteArray("picture", data);

            mFacebook.authorize(this, PERMISSIONS, new LoginDialogListener());
            mAsyncRunner.request("me/photos", params, "POST", new WallPostRequestListener());
            mAsyncRunner.request(response, new WallPostRequestListener());
            Log.e("post result", response);

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return response;
    }

    public class WallPostRequestListener extends BaseRequestListener
    {

        public void onComplete(final String response)
        {
            Log.d("Facebook-Example", "Got response: " + response);
            String message = "<empty>";
            try
            {
                JSONObject json = Util.parseJson(response);
                message = json.getString("message");
            }
            catch (JSONException e)
            {
                Log.w("Facebook-Example", "JSON Error in response");
            }
            catch (FacebookError e)
            {
                Log.w("Facebook-Example", "Facebook Error: " + e.getMessage());
            }
            final String text = "Your Wall Post: " + message;

        }
    }
```

Comment: It is working code, i am able to post my Photo and Message from my SD card to face book wall.......

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure Facebook will fix this eventually, but for the time being these examples (posted by other users) are very misleading because they do NOT in fact post to the user's wall (in the regular sense).  Instead they are added to the user's photo gallery, and then happen to end up on the wall, but not in the same way in which normal posts work... there is no title and no caption and if you add another photo it ends up side by side with the first (rather than as a separate entry).  So, when you use the api command me/feed  it just fails in a spectacular way where it actually adds a post to the wall but it's an empty post from the application (it even disregards the title and caption).

Hopefully Facebook will fix this sometime in the near term.

Answer (score 0):

Posting the image and Text to Facebook wall from code, Once you logged in using facebook credentials.

note : This is applicable only after logging in to your app using facebook credentials

```
sharePhotoToFacebook();                  //function called from any UI event

private void sharePhotoToFacebook(){
        Bitmap bitmap=null;
        String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/Download/";
        try {
            File file = new File(path, "image9.jpg");
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getAbsolutePath());
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            Log.e("Error" , " Error in loading file");
        }

        SharePhoto photo = new SharePhoto.Builder()
                .setBitmap(bitmap)
                .setCaption("A post from Android code")
                .build();

        SharePhotoContent content = new SharePhotoContent.Builder()
                .addPhoto(photo)
                .build();

        ShareApi.share(content, null);
        Toast.makeText(LoginSuccessActivity.this, "Image posted successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```