# How to submit Photos with text together to Facebook wall from Android?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-wall

i'm really stuck on this, i need to post a photo (`byte[]`) and text (`String`) to the Facebook Wall how to do that?

What i'm able to do now is, to upload an image and after that to send a text, so for this i do two post's and that's not cool!

I would appreciate a code example on how to do that?

Thank's in advance....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the documentation of the [User](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/) object, it says under the *photos* connection:

> You can post photos to a user's Wall on their behalf by issuing an
>   HTTP POST request to PROFILE_ID/photos with the publish_stream
>   permissions and the following parameters.

The android fb sdk will do just that for you, it should look something like this:

```
// facebook being either Facebook or AsyncFacebookRunner

Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
parameters.putString("message", "MESSAGE TO GO WITH THE IMAGE");
parameters.putByteArray("source", imageBytes);

facebook.request("me/photos", parameters, "POST");
```

I haven't tested it, and kind of "glued" it together after reading the documentation, the source and some threads ([Async API Requests](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/androidsdk/ayncrequest/), [API Requests](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/androidsdk/request/), [Facebook.java](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/blob/master/facebook/src/com/facebook/android/Facebook.java), [Util.java](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/blob/master/facebook/src/com/facebook/android/Util.java), [Android post picture to Facebook wall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5168145/android-post-picture-to-facebook-wall)). In the last link in the code it says that the parameter name is *picture* instead of the *source* that I used, but that's how it states in the documentation, check it out and see which one works.

Also, you can use *USER-ID/photoes* instead of the *me/photos* graph object path, just make sure that you have the publish_stream permission.

Next time you ask a question, try to be more specific, maybe add the code you have so far?