# Post image on facebook

Tags: java, android, facebook

i want to post image with description on my facebook wall using my android app..

i am using facebook sdk 3.0 .

i followed this guide, however it post only text on my wall without the image:

```
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/androidsdk/3.0/publish-to-feed/
```

how can i post image on my facebook wall with description?

thanks alot

Comment: Try this post:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11050967/how-to-post-image-to-facebook-from-android-app

Comment: i am not sure it's compatible with facebook android sdk 3.0

Comment: Maybe this one? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13083419/facebook-api-3-0-add-bundle-information-to-image-upload

Comment: @tbkn, thanks, what is the Request.Callback callback that i should to insert in the newUploadPhotoRequest method?

Comment: It's a callback you can create to handle the results of the request - success or error. For example displaying a message in the UI. If you don't want a callback you can call the method without the last parameter.

Comment: @tbkn, thanks alot, it work!! however it post a full size image on my facebook wall, is there any way to determine the picture uploaded size? (that it will not very big)

Comment: It depends on the image you upload. If you want a smaller image, use a smaller `GraphObject`. Posted a full answer.

Answer (score 0):

Check this post on how to upload an image to FaceBook:

[Facebook API 3.0. - Add bundle information to image upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13083419/facebook-api-3-0-add-bundle-information-to-image-upload)

You can leave the `Request.Callback` parameter out if you do not want anything to happen once the upload is complete. See this facebook [Reference](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/3.0/Request/#Request%28Session,%20String,%20Bundle,%20HttpMethod,%20Callback%29)

The image size depends on the image file that you upload. The larger the image you upload, the larger it appears in facebook.

This post might help you with resizing the bitmap:

[How to Resize a Bitmap in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4837715/how-to-resize-a-bitmap-in-android)