# How to post comment on facebook photo in android app?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

At present i am struggling to post a comment to a photo on facebook wall .

Can any one direct me the graph-api for posting comment to the facebook photo?

Thanks

Comment: hello! you need to know photo-id. after that, just use: `https://graph.facebook.com/ID_OF_PHOTO/comments?message=MESSAGE&access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN`

Comment: this link might be helpful:
[link][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5168145/android-post-picture-to-facebook-wall

Comment: thank you so much,will try and let you know guys...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, if you want to publish something, you need to use `POST` request for `facebook-graph-api`.

Facebook has a graph structure, so, each thing has connections to other things.

You need to post a message to photo. Ok.

If you have an `access_token`, you can you `POST`-request for `Graph-API`.

OK, after all things, just create an URL for request: `https://graph.facebook.com/PHOTO_ID/comments?message=MESSAGE&access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN` and use `POST`:

`POST https://graph.facebook.com/PHOTO_ID/comments?message=MESSAGE&access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN`

See more information in [Publishing section](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/)

Comment: hai can you tell me how to get the PHOTO_ID. At present i have wall info wat is the tag for Photo_id? will the photo_id will be available in wall info or albums?

Comment: actually, every [post](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/) may contain `object_id` <- this is what you need (photo_id or video_id)

Answer (score 0):

1. Adding the icon

You can manage icons from your app's dashboard: https://developers.facebook.com/apps/APP_ID/appdetails