# Posting Image from Facebook Not Working

Tags: android, facebook

I'm trying to post an image with caption at the user wall in my Android App. But It's not working. It don't display anything  on my wall.

Here is my Codes:

```
    String APP_ID = " My ID";
                fb = new Facebook(APP_ID);
                sp = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
                access_token = sp.getString("access_token", null);
                long expires = sp.getLong("access_expires", 0);

                if(access_token!= null){
                    fb.setAccessToken(access_token);
                }

                if(expires != 0){
                    fb.setAccessExpires(expires);
                }


btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                facebook.authorize(FbdemoActivity.this, new String[]{ "user_photos,publish_checkins,publish_actions,publish_stream"},new DialogListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFacebookError(FacebookError error) {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(DialogError e) {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancel() {
                    }
                });

               posttowall();
            }
        });


public void postToWall() {
        // post on user's wall.
         try {
                if (fb.isSessionValid()) {
                    byte[] data = null;

                     Bitmap bi = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("/sdcard/Asa.jpg");
                     ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                     bi.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
                     data = baos.toByteArray();


                     Bundle params = new Bundle();
                     params.putString(Facebook.TOKEN, fb.getAccessToken());
                     params.putString("message", "Test from Android AVD");
                     params.putString("method", "photos.upload");
                     params.putByteArray("picture", data);

                     AsyncFacebookRunner mAsyncRunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner(fb);
                     mAsyncRunner.request(null, params, "POST", new SampleUploadListener(), null);

                }
            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

    }


public class SampleUploadListener extends BaseRequestListener {

        public void onComplete(final String response, final Object state) {
            try {
                // process the response here: (executed in background thread)
                Log.d("Facebook-Example", "Response: " + response.toString());
                JSONObject json = Util.parseJson(response);
                final String src = json.getString("src");

                // then post the processed result back to the UI thread
                // if we do not do this, an runtime exception will be generated
                // e.g. "CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original
                // thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views."

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.w("Facebook-Example", "JSON Error in response");
            } catch (FacebookError e) {
                Log.w("Facebook-Example", "Facebook Error: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e, Object state) {    
        }
    }
```

It doesn't show any error but it's not posting anything either.
Can anyone point what's missing in my code or what is wrong ?

Comment: `params.putString("method", "photos.upload")` : - where did you get this line? that's from the old API, are you sure you're not using an old example using outdated SDKs?

Comment: Check this link :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5168145/android-post-picture-to-facebook-wall

Comment: where can I get the newest Api?

Answer (score 0):

Yes i s seen one problem in your code 
one Permission missing..

```
  String[] permissions = { "offline_access", "publish_stream", "user_photos", "publish_checkins",
        **"photo_upload"** };
```

Add this permission then check it...

Comment: I already add the permission but still not posting anything even the "message"

Comment: Your should check HACK book example of Facebook...its available in FACKBOOK ANDROID SDK..

Comment: http://developers.facebook.com/android/downloads/ You should download it for this link