# How to post drawable image on facebook

Tags: android, android-drawable, facebook-sdk-3.0

Hi I am new to android programming. I am creating a app in which user can share a specific image on facebook. Image is present in my drawable folder. Everything works fine except posting image. I mean I have successfully posted link an description but not image.
I have tried may almost every code snippet, present on stackoverflow, to fix this issue but all in vain.

Please help me in solving this problem. Bundle of thanks in advance!

```
fb= new Facebook(app_id);

     byte[] data = null;


     Bitmap bi = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), mImageIds[pos]);
     ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
     bi.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
     data = baos.toByteArray();



    Bundle params = new Bundle(); 
    params.putString("message", "Yasin");
    params.putString("link", "http://www.google.com");
    params.putString("name", "Yasin"); 
    params.putByteArray("picture", data);
    params.putString("description", "This is description"); 
     // displaying facebook dialogs
    fb.dialog(con, "feed", params,new DialogListener() {

        @Override
        public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(DialogError e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```

Comment: Did you try this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5168145/android-post-picture-to-facebook-wall

Comment: Yes. It opens up a facebook window (activity) with a progress bar. After 2-4 sec that goes away and nothing happens.